# How to extract the value of the key, in this string

Tags: java

I have the following string i need to access the CN and O values using java,
how do i do that?

`jQuery2038205_146921({"name":"cn=cdf,o=abc","expiration":"656"});`

Comment: Looks like a JSON (except the `jQuery2038205_146921()` part), so maybe use a JSON parser like gson or jackson

Comment: One solution: split on `"`, take the 4th element, split it on `,`, split each of the results on `=`. The "correct" solution depends on what actual data you expect, creating a solution for one sample is pointless.

Comment: I am modifying elasticsearch,so external jar's like json,gson doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can use following regex for this and capture values from group1 and group2.

Java code,

```
String s = "jQuery2038205_146921({\"name\":\"cn=cdf,o=abc\",\"expiration\":\"656\"});";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bcn=([^,\"]+),o=([^,\"]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("CN: %s, O: %s", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

Prints,

```
CN: cdf, O: abc
```

On the other hand, if the order of two strings can be different then two regex needs to be used like this,

```
String s = "jQuery2038205_146921({\"name\":\"cn=cdf,o=abc\",\"expiration\":\"656\"});";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\bcn=([^,\"]+)");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\bo=([^,\"]+)");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s);
if (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println("CN: " + m1.group(1));
}
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(s);
if (m2.find()) {
    System.out.println("O: " + m2.group(1));
}
```

Prints,

```
CN: cdf
O: abc
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the input is an LDAP string, and the position of `cn` and `o` may not always be fixed (and there could be other attributes, too).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I have given the solution for given string. In case it the two strings order can be different, two separate regex will have to be used.

Comment: Added solution for case where two strings can be present in any order.

Comment: Please share the reason of downvote too. I will be happy to accept and solve any issues in my solution. Or let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think the capture group of both regexes should be `([^,\"]+)` (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Lino: Although it would have been enough to write just `\w+` because OP didn't specify the character set and its a very minor change to do. Thanks for your input, updated the charset.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a JSON parser, then do that.  If not, here are some one-liners which might also work:

```
String input = "jQuery2038205_146921({\"name\":\"cn=cdf,o=abc\",\"expiration\":\"656\"});";
String cn = input.replaceAll(".*\\bcn=([^\",]+).*", "$1");
String o = input.replaceAll(".*\\bo=([^\",]+).*", "$1");
System.out.println(cn);
System.out.println(o);

cdf
abc
```